# How to get all frameId's in a tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a way to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to get all `frameId`'s in a tab?

I tried `executeScript()` then have the code send a message to background which would send it back to the content with the `frameId`, however it's async. And, `executeScript()` needs sync return.

Comment: `chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames` might be faster but it's also async. The only way to have a "sync" list is to populate it before it's actually needed.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I am unsure as to where you need this information. Do you need it for a call to `tabs.executeScript()`, or do you need it actually in the content script. If in the content script, why do you need the actual `frameId` there (just interested)? If you need it in the content script, a couple of ways come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get a list of frameId's for a tab using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript)).As it sounds like you have determined, it is a bit convoluted to do so. You could use `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` with the option `allFrames:true` to inject a content script into all frames in the tab. Your content script would then need to send a message back to the background context using [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage)).  The `frameId` will then be available for each frame as a property of the Object passed as the second argument, the [`sender`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-MessageSender) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/MessageSender)), to your [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage)) listener. You will need to accumulate the list yourself.

### A much better way: use [`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#method-getAllFrames) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/getAllFrames))

As wOxxOm mentioned in a comment, It would be much easier to get it from [`chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#method-getAllFrames) ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/getAllFrames)).

There is no way to obtain a list of frameId's for a tab using a synchronous interface. As wOxxOm also mentioned, the only way to do it is to obtain the information prior to you needing it. If you need it for a call to `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`, then you can make the call to `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` from the callback for `chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames()`.

Comment: Perfect! The `chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames() ` works a treat!! Thanks my brother!